# Pros and Cons of Block Cipher's Mode of Operations?

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation

What are the Pros and Cons of Block Cipher's Modes of Operations(ECB, CBC, CTR, OFB, CCM, GCM) in terms of

1. Confidentiality
2. Integrity
3. CPA
4. Restrictions on IV or Counter/Nonce
5. Maximum number of Block which can be encrypted without compromising the security
6. Speed
7. Parallelism while encrypting and Decrypting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a *very* broad question and a complete answer would probably fill an entire chapter in a book. You're asking for comparison of $6$ modes of operation in $7$ different areas - and each one of those comparisons could be stated as an individual question - actually it often is. Therefore I'll just link to some similar questions on this site, which should provide plenty of information:

- [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher) and [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/225/should-i-use-ecb-or-cbc-encryption-mode-for-my-block-cipher) adress the comparison between ECB and CBC.
- [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/aes-cbc-mode-or-aes-ctr-mode-recommended) adresses the comparison between CBC and CTR, with a reference to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/block-chaining-modes-to-avoid/27780#27780) on security-SE (which also takes note of OFB).
- [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/aes-ccm-vs-ccmp) and ask about AES-CCM compared to CCMP
- [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10808/4082) compares GCM to various other constructions, e.g. CBC+HMAC
- [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/is-aes-gcm-parallelizable) asks if AES-GCM can be parallelized

Also, we even have individual tags for [modes of operation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modes-of-operation), [ECB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecb), [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cbc), [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ctr), [CFB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfb), [OFB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ofb),  [GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcm), [CCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ccm), and maybe there are even more.

Since I don't know what research you have done so far, the only other pointer I could give is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), but surely you already checked that.

Comment: not a fan of the question but the links made for nice reading, hence the up vote